# PHP Parsing User ID from Slack Response

Tags: php, regex, slack-api

In Slack, when you @mention someone, slack will pass off the response like this to an api:

> Example response <@U7J3C4AKB|john.doe> from slack

Where the @U7J3C4AKB is the user_id, and the latter is the username. What regular expression can be use to parse the user_id from the response?

Comment: `@\w+` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JF7Y3Y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
/@\w+/
```

`@` matches the character `@` literally (case sensitive)
`\w+` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

stops at pipe `|`

https://regex101.com/r/sq08Ns/1

Answer (score 0):

To match the username after the `<` unitil the pipe `|`, you could use:

[`<\K@[^|]+`](https://regex101.com/r/Dp2hvs/1)

That would match:

- `<`
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match
- `@`
- `[^|]+` Match not a pipe one or more times